# Disable loading flash component in second tab

Tags: php, flash

I have problem on my site, when user open one php page with flash component **in two tabs**, and he logs out from one tab, flash component in other tab stays active, but session is broken, and he can see component although he is practically logged out.

I need idea how to implement that if user have page opened in one tab, he can't open same page in other tab, and write like 'you already have opened this page' or something like that.

Thanks, and hope that explanation is clear enough. Please ask if something is vague.